# Strange Destruction of objects

Tags: c++, destructor

I am puzzled why the destructor is being called so many times.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Box
{
    public:
        int x;
        Box(int x);
        ~Box();
};

Box::~Box()
{
    std::cout << x << " Destroyed\n";
}

Box::Box(int x)
{
    this->x = x;
    std::cout << x << " Created\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Box> boxList;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Box b(i);
        boxList.push_back(b);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
0 Created
0 Destroyed
1 Created
0 Destroyed
1 Destroyed
2 Created
0 Destroyed
1 Destroyed
2 Destroyed
```

After main exits this will be printed. I kept a getchar() in the destructor to stop the program execution. Otherwise we will not see these lines being printed.

```
0 Destroyed
1 Destroyed
2 Destroyed
```

Can someone please explain.

Comment: That's because `boxList.push_back(b);` copies your object instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers correctly mention the invocation of the implicit [copy constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/). To see these invocations, just replace the implicit copy constructor with an explicit copy constructor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Box
{
    public:
        int x;
        int copy_nr;
        Box(int x);
        Box(const Box& other); //copy constructor
        ~Box();
};

Box::~Box()
{
    std::cout << x << " (copy " << copy_nr << ") Destroyed" << std::endl;
}

Box::Box(int x) : x(x), copy_nr(0)
{
    std::cout << x << " (copy " << copy_nr << ") Created" << std::endl;
}

Box::Box(const Box& other) : x( other.x ), copy_nr( other.copy_nr + 1 )
{
        std::cout << x << " (copy " << other.copy_nr <<") Copied"
                     " (creating copy " << copy_nr << ")" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Box> boxList;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Box b(i);
        boxList.push_back(b);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

On my machine, this produces:

```
0 (copy 0) Created
0 (copy 0) Copied (creating copy 1)
0 (copy 0) Destroyed
1 (copy 0) Created
1 (copy 0) Copied (creating copy 1)
0 (copy 1) Copied (creating copy 2)
0 (copy 1) Destroyed
1 (copy 0) Destroyed
2 (copy 0) Created
2 (copy 0) Copied (creating copy 1)
0 (copy 2) Copied (creating copy 3)
1 (copy 1) Copied (creating copy 2)
0 (copy 2) Destroyed
1 (copy 1) Destroyed
2 (copy 0) Destroyed
0 (copy 3) Destroyed
1 (copy 2) Destroyed
2 (copy 1) Destroyed
```

Results might differ on other machines, as the implementation of `std::vector` can decide when to reallocate its internal array.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons for this.

Firstly, `push_back` sometimes extends the size of the vector, reallocating the space, copying all objects there, and destroying old objects. To get rid of the artifacts of this reallocation, you can add `boxList.reserve(3)` before the loop, and get a more understandable output:

```
0 Created
0 Destroyed
1 Created
1 Destroyed
2 Created
2 Destroyed
0 Destroyed
1 Destroyed
2 Destroyed
```

Secondly, `push_back` makes a copy of your local `b` object, and after this `b` is destroyed. This explains why each object in the output above is destroyed soon after being created.

The final three calls are, of course, at program exit.

Answer (score 0):

> 0 Created

The local Box b(0) is created, copied to vector

> 0 Destroyed

and destroyed

> 1 Created

Now the local Box b(1) is created

> 0 Destroyed

I think at this moment your vector got reallocated and needed to copy objects to its new storage. The object with index 0 in the original vector is destroyed in the process

> 1 Destroyed

The local Box is destroyed

> 2 Created

Now its time for the local Box with index 2

> 0 Destroyed
>   1 Destroyed

And again vector got reallocated and needed to destroy objects in the original location

> 2 Destroyed

The local variable destroyed

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `vector` is using the default copy operator of `Box` to create a second instance of the object, bypassing the constructor you have defined. Effectively, you really do have two instances of `Box`: `b` and `boxList[i]`.

Note what happens to the compiler if you explicitly define an assignment operator as private:

```
class Box
{
    public:
        int x;
        Box(int x);
        ~Box();

    private:
        Box& operator=( const Box& second ) {};
};
```

The flood of compiler errors within std are due to its use of operator= internally to create exact copies of your `b` object.

Answer (score 0):

you will get an automaticly generated copy-constructor.
if you replace

```
Box b(i);
boxList.push_back(b);
```

with

```
boxList.emplace_back(i);
```

you get insite construction.
if you also use `reserve(3)` (before adding items), the vector wont have to move things around (another possible cause of calling the destructor), then the the destructor should be called exactly 3 times